# CSS background transition doesn´t work on IE, Firefox and Safari, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Good evening everybody!

I wrote a JavaScript that slides through a several amount of images with a fade effect.
In Chrome and Opera it workes fine, but in the other browsers the pictures switch but the fade effect doesn´t work.. I don´t know why.

**Here is my css for my body background:**

```
body{
    -webkit-transition: background 1.5s ease;
        -moz-transition: background 1.5s ease;
        -o-transition: background 1.5s ease;
        -ms-transition: background 1.5s ease;
        transition: background 1.5s ease;
}
```

You see I dont forget the prefixes!

**Here is my JavaScript:**

```
var rnd_last = -1;
var picInterval;
var picsArray = new Array('url(hd1.jpg)', 'url(hd2.jpg)', 'url(hd3.jpg)', 'url(hd4.jpg)');

$('document').ready(function() {

    startPicInterval();

    $(window).resize(function()
    {
        clearInterval(picInterval);
        startPicInterval();
    });


});

function setBodyBackground(actualPic)
{
    $('body').css({'background-image': actualPic});
}

function startPicInterval()
{

    if ($(window).width() >= 1200)
    {
        picInterval = setInterval(function() {
            setBodyBackground(picsArray[getRandomNumber(1, picsArray.length)]);
        }, 5000);
    }


}

function getRandomNumber(min, max)
{
    var rnd;
    do
    {
        rnd = Math.floor((Math.random() * max) + min);
    } while (rnd === rnd_last);
    rnd_last = rnd;
    return(rnd);

}
```

I hope anybody can help me, grateful Nico!

Comment: `background-image` is not an animatable property: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-properties

Comment: oke but why it works on chrome and opera?

and what solution would you recommend me to reach the same effect and solve my problem?
Grateful Nico

Comment: Some browsers may be able to interpret it, but if it's not part of the spec, it will not be cross-browser compliant. My suggestion would be to use Javascript, here is a Fiddle with similar functionality: http://jsfiddle.net/M2LmH/

Comment: I try your code and it works fine, but still not in firefox or internet explorer..

I would something like [this](http://www.trapa.at)

Comment: @APAD1 Your code doesn´t work by me, I dont know why. I don´t use your "full-page" wrapper I use always 'body' for the functions in js, is that a problem?
Grateful Nico